# How do I write to a __user memory from within the top half of an interrupt handler?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory, interrupt

I am working on a proprietary device driver. The driver is implemented as a kernel module. This module is then coupled with an user-space process.

It is essential that each time the device generates an interrupt, the driver updates a set of counters directly in the address space of the user-space process from within the top half of the interrupt handler. The driver knows the PID and the task_struct of the user-process and is also aware of the virtual address where the counters lie in the user-process context. However, I am having trouble in figuring out how code running in the interrupt context could take up the mm context of the user-process and write to it. Let me sum up what I need to do:

1. Get the address of the physical page and offset corresponding to the virtual address of the counters in the context of the user-process.
2. Set up mappings in the page table and write to the physical page corresponding to the counter.

For this, I have tried the following:

1. Try to take up the mm context of the user-task, like below:

   ```
       use_mm(tsk->mm); 
       /* write to counters. */
       unuse_mm(tsk->mm);
   ```

   This apparently causes the entire system to hang.
2. Wait for the interrupt to occur when our user-process was the
   `current` process. Then use `copy_to_user()`.

I'm not much of an expert on kernel programming. If there's a good way to do this, please do advise and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your driver should be the one, who **maps** kernel's memory for user space process. E.g., you may implement `.mmap` callback for `struct file_operation` for your device.

Kernel driver may write to kernel's address, which it have mapped, at any time (even in interrupt handler). The user-space process will immediately see all modifications on its side of the mapping (using address obtained with `mmap()` system call).

Comment: This is arguably the 'correct' way to do things. It works with the kernel design, not against it.

Answer (score 2):

Unix's architecture frowns on interrupt routines accessing user space
because a process could (in theory) be swapped out when the interrupt occurs. 
If the process is running on another CPU, that could be a problem, too. 
I suggest that you write an ioctl to synchronize the counters,
and then have the the process call that ioctl
every time it needs to access the counters.

Comment: It's designed to only work on single CPU architectures. In the second approach as mentioned in my question, copy_to_user() fails. However, I am surprised to observe that if I dereference the virtual address and write to it directly from within my driver module when the last process context prior to the interrupt was my user process, the counter is updated correctly in user-space. I suppose this not fail-safe, since there could be potential page-faults?

Answer (score 2):

Outside of an interrupt context, your driver will need to check the user memory is accessible (using `access_ok`), and pin the user memory using `get_user_pages` or `get_user_pages_fast` (after determining the page offset of the start of the region to be pinned, and the number of pages spanned by the region to be pinned, including page alignment at both ends). It will also need to map the list of pages to kernel address space using `vmap`. The return address from `vmap`, plus the offset of the start of the region within its page, will give you an address that your interrupt handler can access.

At some point, you will want to terminate access to the user memory, which will involve ensuring that your interrupt routine no longer accesses it, a call to `vunmap` (passing the pointer returned by `vmap`), and a sequence of calls to `put_page` for each of the pages pinned by `get_user_pages` or `get_user_pages_fast`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Consider this situation:
(assuming how your device works)

1. Some function allocates the user-space memory for the counters and
   supplies its address in PROCESS X.
2. A switch occurs and PROCESS Y executes.
3. Your device interrupts.

The address for your counters is inaccessible.

You need to schedule a kernel mode asynchronous event (lower half) that will execute when PROCESS X is executing.

Comment: In the interrupt context, I kind of check whether `current == my_task`, where `my_task` is a reference to the task structure of my user process. I update user-space memory if and only if the check returns true. Doesn't that mean that VA mappings are in the context of my user process when the device is interrupted?

Comment: What if there is a context change after that check and before the update? Are you able to block all interrupts?

Comment: I have `preempt_disable()` before that check but I don't know if that's enough.